# Your device isn't compatible with this version - Android PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I have created and apk file using phonegap builder and uploaded it on play store.

Now my problem is, on some of the handsets like samsung galaxy note 2, the play store search is not able to find my app.

On accessing the URL through a QR Code I get the play store page but it says "**Your device isn't compatible with this version**".

I am unable to understand why it is so. I don't face this problem on samsung galaxy grand or some of the other phones that I tried i.e. the play store search is able to find my app and I am able to successfully install and use it.

Can someone please help me with this. I have been searching the internet from past 2 days without much of an help. I feel somehow the problem is with the config.xml file.

Below is the copy of my xml file (if it helps).

I will be really grateful to you for all your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.xxx.yyy"
        version   = "1.0.0"
        versionCode = "213">
    <name>yyy</name>

    <author href="http://www.abcxyz.com" email="contact@gmail.com">
        XYZ
    </author>

    <gap:platform name="android" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

    <access origin="*"/>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
    <preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />

    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="18" />
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="10000"/>

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="images/icon36.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon48.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon72.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon96.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <gap:splash src="images/screen.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/screen.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/screen.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/screen.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Can you show full manifest?

Comment: I don't have a AndroidManifest.xml file. Is it something I need to define if i have developed the app using PhoneGap and JQuery ? I am really sorry, it might be a really stupid question. I am very new to app development

Comment: May be a similar [issue](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/214) which was solved after updating Phonegap version. You may try

Comment: But in my case the problem is it is not working on Galaxy Note 2 (Android 4.4.2) where as it works perfectly find on Samsung Galaxy Grand (Android 4.2.2). Is it somewhere related to maxSdkVersion that I have set?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to fixed it. On replying to MysticMagic's comments, I somehow realized my mistake. Thanks MysticMagic, for making me think right.

The handsets that i was trying on, had KitKat version of OS whereas I had restricted my application to Jelly Bean.
So I had to just change the below code from

```
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="18" />
```

to

```
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="19" />
```